# Module.js 491 cant find module ngx-bootstrap angular 4

Tags: angular

My app works fine in development as well as in production environment but when I am deploying it on test website it's giving me this error. I haven't used `ngx bootstrap` in my code and I have uninstalled and installed node modules again. but nothing seems to work. can someone help me
here is the error

> module.js:491 0|Web-Stag |throw err; 0|Web-Stag |     ^ Error: Cannot
>   find module 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-backdrop.component'

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mutterfly",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "To Mutterfly",
  "description": "Mutterfly Website",
  "author": "Akshat Jain <akshatjain1995.aj@gmail.com>",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "development": "concurrently --kill-others \"nodemon server.js --watch server.js --watch server\" \"ng serve -o --proxy-config proxy.config.json\"",
    "staging": "ng build --aot=ture && node server.js",
    "production": "ng build --prod --aot=true && ng build --prod --app app-server --output-hashing none && ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@ionic/cli-utils": "^1.19.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.78",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-slick-carousel": "^3.1.7",
    "angular2-polyfill": "0.0.32",
    "angular2-social-login": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mydaterangepicker": "^4.1.9",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.5.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.26",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.2",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your package.json?

Comment: Please check I have added it in the question itself

Comment: Execute `npm-prune` in the working directory and see if it works?

Comment: It says its updated

Comment: Try to install `ngx-bootstrap` plugin using this command `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`

Comment: @hrdkisback If it were a transitive dependency `npm` would have pulled it from the repo, IO is quite specific that issue is faced in the deployment phase.

Comment: Any solution guys? This is really not solving anything

Comment: In `package.json` I think it should be `--aot=true` not `--aot=ture`.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your  help. I have solved it. I have server side rendering in my code and to push the code on stage I needed to set hashing and other things in ecoconfig thats what I changed and it worked. :)